Obtain type annotation of a function argument
Since Python 3.5 type aliases are available (with a simplified syntax since 3.12),
type T = int # introduces type alias T
t: T = 1     # annotates t as type T

The type annotation of variable t can be found in the __annotations__ dict
>>> __annotations__['t']
"T"

Is it possible to determine the annotation of a variable that was passed as an argument to a function? E.g. when above t is passed to a function, f(t)
def f(x):
    # what is the type annotation of the variable passed in as x (if any)?
    pass

Unfortunately the annotation of the variable passed into a function is not maintained in the local frame of the function.
Therefore my conclusion is that the type annotation is just not available in the function body anymore. Is this assessment correct?

My feeling is that this information should actually not be passed into the function. The type should be annotated (again) in the function declaration, so that a checker can verify that the function is called with the correct type(s); that seems a large part of the purpose of typing: matching function signatures with their calls. Passing the type annotation along with the variable to a function defeats that purpose.

Also: do type aliases have to do anything with your question about passing annotations to a function? If you used t: int = 1, so without an alias, I think the question is still the same: does the type of t get passed to def f(x):?

@9769953 yes this is specifically about type aliases. Inside the function type(t) is int, but it's int because 1 is int, not because the type annotation says so.
But I agree, carrying along the type annotation into the function is at odds with the dynamic nature of Python.

Hm, and what about t: float = 1? 1 is still an int, but t is a float. So that type annotation makes this an implicit cast.

(It may be that I see an alias simply as a substitutions, like a #define is in C. Not sure if it really works that way in Python.)

Yes, t: float = 1 is still an int, even if the __annotations__ dict says float. I think the purpose is purely for IDEs to draw squiggly lines under t: float = 1 (which they don't actually do, funnily - at least vscode doesn't).

t: float = 1 is fine because this is a special case. See also these two recent forum posts: Clarifying the float/int/complex special case and Options for a long term fix of the special case for float/int/complex.


Therefore my conclusion is that the type annotation is just not available in the function body anymore. Is this assessment correct?

Yes. As you have noticed, the annotations are stored separately in a magic global dict, not carried along with the variable itself.
Inspecting variable annotations is perhaps not a good idea, especially when it comes to local variables, whose annotations cannot be found in __annotations__.
